# which method need to call first in class based views django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am new to django framework. I want to know about class based views methods in django. I jus learned what are all the methods used in class based views such as get_context_data, get,post etc... Can anyone explain me about the workflow in class based views with example. I am so confused with it. Please clarify anyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the docs... You just have to read them.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/mixins/

Comment: I can't get it clearly. That's y am asking here for help. If you don't mind can you explain it with example.. it will be helpful to continue.

Comment: It would take a long time to explain everything... Check this tutorial, it should be easy to understand http://lgiordani.com/blog/2013/10/28/digging-up-django-class-based-views-1/